# As a new user, should I be concerned about downvotes on my answers?

Tags: support, answers, reputation, downvotes

I searched on Meta and Googled but didn't find the answer. Or if I did, it was embedded in a more complicated question that I didn't understand.

How do downvotes on my answers affect my rep?

Comment: In the black bar at the top, you have the stackexchange menu, the icon for your message inbox and then an icon that represents a graph. Click that graph icon and answer your own question, hopefully.

Comment: You'll get -2 if someone down votes your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: _"How do downvotes on my answers affect my rep?"_ Didn't you notice this? And yes downvotes should concern you, take a look at the tooltip message appearing when you hover your mouse pointer over the downvote button.

Comment: It's in the help: [Help Center > Privileges > Vote Down](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

Comment: Sometimes downvotes are justified and indicative of a quality problem; sometimes not. For constructive responses we're going to need an example.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the comments everyone. Thanks especially to rene for pointing out the link I should have found myself - https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation . That explains exactly how downvotes on answers affect rep.

Comment: You're welcome. Enjoy your stay on Stack Overflow.